# grid like format for NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios5

How can i format my NSString to be something like

```
1  Item1  7.00  0%  7.00
1  Item2  6.00  0%  6.00
```

i'm getting the string from html it is in table format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEEE printf flags to specify field widths (it's in the iOS library documentation).  That means that if you have the content of the table cells as separate values or objects, you can create your fixed-space string using NSString's `stringWithFormat:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it solves your problem?

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i \t %@ \t %.2f %%%i %.2f",1,@"Item1",7.00,0,6.00];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: But what i'm doing is get the text from the table using $("tableid").text() or the html $(tableid).html()